# JavaScript confirm box not appearing on PHP page

Tags: php

Can anyone see why this line in PHP doesn't work. The game card is deleted, but the confirm box does not appear for the user to okay or cancel.

```
echo "<a href='gamecard.php?selection=" . $row['gamedate'] . " onclick='return confirm('Delete game card?');'>Delete</a>";
```

Thank you.

Comment: You are using nested single quotes in your onclick, try escaping them?

Comment: The PHP part is not really meaningful here. What gets output in the browser and what errors do you get in the error console?

Comment: You have a nested set of single quotes in the `onclick` and an unclosed single quote on the `href`

Comment: Basic structure: <a href="myUrl" onclick="confirm('Delete game card?');">Delete</a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have single quotes inside of single quotes, you need to escape 'em.  You also forgot the closing quote on the `href` attribute.

```
echo "<a href='gamecard.php?selection=" . $row['gamedate'] . "' onclick='return confirm(\"Delete game card?\");'>Delete</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some issues with missing quotes and using double quotes when you should be using singles (and vice/versa). This should do the trick.

```
echo "<a href='gamecard.php?selection=" . $row['gamedate'] . "' onclick='return confirm(\"Delete game card?\");'>Delete</a>";
```

Comment: You need to escape the `"` inside `confirm`.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<a href='gamecard.php?selection=" . $row['gamedate'] . "' onclick=\"confirm('Delete game card?');\">Delete</a>";
```

will do it. HTML attributes, as a general practice, should be double quoted. JS strings should be single quoted.

Comment: You need to escape the `"` around `onclick`.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<a href=\"gamecard.php?selection=" . $row['gamedate'] . "\" onclick=\"return confirm('Delete game card?');\">Delete</a>";
```

**[codepad example](http://codepad.org/F0rtXgj3)**